# UK Work visa issue Tier 2

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens, europe

I am an Indian with a Tier 2 general visa/ UK work permit from my employer for 6 months (with sponsorship certificate). I will be visiting UK from this April, 2016 to August, 2016. I am also interested to visit neighbouring countries, while I will be in Europe on weekends. The problem is my work permit visa's multiple re-entry required field is No.

**Does the migrant need to leave and re-enter the UK during the period of approval? N**

Can I get a visitor visa to other countries or it is not possible (as per my understanding) because once I leave UK then my work permit would expire?

Comment: That sounds more like wording that would be on an _application_ for a work permit than wording that would be on the permit/visa itself. Are you sure it is the latter? If you really have only one entry, then of course you cannot leave the UK and then expect to enter once more; there's not much to mistake there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure, you need to look at the UK entry clearance which is attached to a page of your passport.

[image: UK Tier 2 entry clearance]

On the second line, "Number of entries" will tell you how many entries you may make. This may say 1, 2, or MULT. If it says MULT, this is a multiple entry visa and you may exit and re-enter as many times as you wish.